# Creating an extendible class that implements an extendible event emitter

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create a series of extendible classes that, at each level, can add additional event handlers to an "EventMap" structure that is used as to type check an `emit()` method.

```
class Level1_Extendible (Events: 'deliver1')
 |  
 | 
 |-> class Level2_Extendible (Events: 'deliver1' | 'deliver2')
      |  
      |-> class Level3_Final (Events: 'deliver1' | 'deliver2' | 'deliver3')
```

This is very much an EventEmitter pattern, but extendible over multiple levels of base classes. The idea seems pretty simple in my head using generics with constraints etc. It all works fine for the final non-extendible class. But the base classes do not allow access to the events that they should already know about:

- Level1_Extendible can't emit 'deliver1'
- Level2_Extendible can't emit 'deliver2' or 'deliver1'
- Level3_Final, however, can emit 'deliver3', 'deliver2' and 'deliver1'

```
interface EventMap1 {
    deliver1(): void;
}

class Level1_Extendable<EM extends EventMap1 = EventMap1> {
    emit<Key extends keyof EM>(key: Key, ...args: EventEmitterParameters<EM[Key]>): void {
        // Emit the event...
    }

    doSomething() {
        // This statement errors
        this.emit('deliver1');
    }
}

interface EventMap2 extends EventMap1 {
    deliver2(): void;
}

class Level2_Extendable<EM extends EventMap2 = EventMap2> extends Level1_Extendable<EM> {
    doSomething() {
        // Both of these statements error
        this.emit('deliver1');
        this.emit('deliver2');
    }
}

interface EventMap3 extends EventMap2 {
    deliver3(payload: boolean): void;
}

class Level3_Final extends Level2_Extendable<EventMap3> {
    doSomething() {
        // These statements are fine!
        this.emit('deliver1');
        this.emit('deliver2');
        this.emit('deliver3', true);
    }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAogbhAdsGBbAlsYEBOAFAQxwNQmxwGcAePAewovQCMAbCAMQFdEBjYdWogB8UALwAoKFKgBtOg2ZsuvfoIC6UCAA9siACYVZACgB0ZogHMKALigFEIGWoCUYkfZBrJ0nwH5vPoFQhMSk5NTyjKwc3HwCwgGB1olBUk4A3OLi6Mi4AGYEPNDwSMAAsgRgAIxQAN6JehAs6Ag4VUbOtnC06HqZAL5ZPCwEDFAAMhAILFUA%20jA6SHoE0VQwZZqL%20oYlyBXVYrAIe5VVIvU%20EBjAVADSECCbugZQANYPtHmwZUJG7yC2e4gAA0UDMJksNiOpTQmHIIRIZFw1HWMiBaiEnSg3V6dRS0gA9ATYNcoMAABbQKalcGJQYNWgAZVoYXJOQsHTxqSgRKgABU2YYKMACNhSMhNDgcLRKPipBT0BQTFdMEYAOSNZqtKpq5yZHyDek5cgFIrQk5gABMTyWO2O5VOXOkmpauEtHS6PT64npw1Ghkm00t8y2y1W6xt23NDqth12MctIm0zwD1JmIeeKzYax%20TqkeiZLLIbMQHNcF1SvIAQrQKVBPmTKRRoMLRVdSoZcNKcHLG4rldd1S7tbr9akFUqVcAh01XThLaO6T6ssb8oVivb9gBmSMveP7a0V-Oz1pboxgAggFi0Ah6WxMWi0Nj2LE472%20kZjQNNLezdg5AgWF3VMgwzJYswgNZN0qLdzgZZlWXZTkj0CXkBQgZsoFbMUOzsHBoDyHIIAAQl7CcB1VDUT1wHU9TIwUKOnKitTdRduXIqcZxYnAtzVUFgBwTgIDog0fSAA).

It seems the unresolved generics get in the way, even though the base classes should know about the properties that they add to the mix based on the generic constraints. Anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong here, another way this can be achieved or if what I'm trying to do is not possible currently? Thanks!

Comment: The problem is that `EventEmitterParameters<M[K]>` is a conditional type that depends on at least one as-yet-unspecified type parameter, so the compiler defers evaluating it.  It is essentially opaque; the compiler has no idea what values may or may not be assignable to it, so it treats all values as not assignable (the safe but annoying option).  As for how to fix it, that's hard to say; I can't come up with a pretty way.  You could work around it by overloading `emit()` like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WY49rm), but that might be too annoying for you.  Thoughts?

Comment: Note that [ms/TS#38685](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38685) is relevant

Comment: There's also [this workaround](https://tsplay.dev/NnK96m) where you cal the methods on `this` after upcasting `this` to the non-generic class type.  I can write up that one if you'd prefer

Comment: @jcalz I def want to avoid manual overloading. It's a bit rough on the ergonomics I'm striving for with my project. Especially given that there are many other EventEmitter methods that would need the same treatment. The `thiz` workaround is a bit much too :(, a little better is perhaps defining `this` in the parameter list, but I think both are a bit cumbersome / unintuitive for the client. I've been banging my head on this all day so thanks for the response as always! But I guess I'll advise users that want to make an extensible class to use this trick.

Comment: So, should I not write up an answer at all?  What do you want to see?

Comment: @jcalz Upcasting `this` in the parameter list will do for me and hopefully can help others.

Comment: Perhaps the overload option would be good to include as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here seems to be that the compiler *defers* evaluation of `EventEmitterParameters<EM["deliver1"]>` inside the implementation of `Level1_Extendable<EM>`'s `emit()`, since it is a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) that depends upon the as-yet unspecified [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter `EM extends EventMap1`.  Instead of spending a lot of processing time probing generic conditional types for possible non-generic subtypes and supertypes, which would often be wasted, the compiler essentially gives up.  It doesn't know *what* `EventEmitterParameters<EM["deliver1"]>` is going to be, so it treats it as an opaque type to which no value of almost any other type is seen as assignable.  This is a general limitation of generic conditional types in TypeScript. See [microsoft/TypeScript#43638](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43638) for more information, and [microsoft/TypeScript#38685](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38685) for a related feature request.

If `EM` were *specified* as `EventMap1` or `EventMap2` or `EventMap3`, then the problem goes away. You see this inside `Level3_Final`.  If you want similar behavior inside `Level1_Extendable` or `Level2_Extendable`, you might need to upcast `this` from [the polymorphic `this` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-types) to a specific type of the current class.  There are different ways to do this; you prefer specifying the [`this` parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-parameters) for the `doSomething()` method implementation, which looks like this:

```
doSomething(this: Level1_Extendable) {
    this.emit('deliver1'); // okay
}
```

and:

```
doSomething(this: Level2_Extendable) {
    this.emit('deliver1'); // okay
    this.emit('deliver2'); // okay
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAogbhAdsGBbAlsYEBOAFAQxwNQmxwGcAePAewovQCMAbCAMQFdEBjYdWogB8UALwAoKFKgBtOg2ZsuvfoIC6UCAA9siACYVZACgB0ZogHMKALigFEIGWoCUYkfZAaA-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-YakAA)